# How to prove that $\Delta CFE $ is similar to $\Delta CED.$

Tags: geometry

Choose a point $C$ outside a circle, and a ray from $C$ cuts the circle at $F$ and $D$. Prove that $\Delta CFE\simeq\Delta CED.$ $E$ is a point where one of the two tangents from $C$ meets the circle.

[image]

Obviously, 
$$\angle C= \angle C$$
I just need to prove that 
$$\angle CED =\angle CFE$$
Or 
$$\angle CEF =\angle CDE$$
I tried to find all the possible angle relationships I could, but I am still not able to prove any of the two conditions above. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that
$$\angle CEF =\angle CDE$$
draw the diameter $EE'$ which is clearly perpendicular to $CE$ and hence
$$\angle CEF +\angle FEE'=90^\circ$$
and hence
$$
\angle EE'F =\angle CEF
$$
But
$$
\angle EE'F=\angle CDE
$$
since they are inscribed angles looking at the same arc.

Hence
$$\angle CEF =\angle CDE$$

Answer (score 1):

Note:
$$CE^2=CF\cdot CD \iff \frac{CF}{CD}=\left(\frac{CE}{CD}\right)^2.$$
and:
$$S_{\Delta CEF}=\frac12\cdot CE\cdot CF\cdot \sin \angle ECF; \ \ \ \ \ \\
S_{\Delta CDE}=\frac12\cdot CE\cdot CD\cdot \sin \angle ECD; \\
\frac{S_{\Delta CEF}}{S_{\Delta CDE}}=\frac{CF}{CD}=\left(\frac{CE}{CD}\right)^2 \Rightarrow \Delta CEF \sim\Delta CDE.$$